# Facebook mail in email client Thunderbird

Tags: facebook, smtp, pop3, email-client, thunderbird

I could use FB mail (nick at facebook dot com) in Mozilla Thunderbird but i dont know options pop3 and smtp servers. And is it possible use that external mail client? thx

Answer (score 2):

You can't use your Facebook mail with Thunderbird or any other email client. Facebook have arranged things such that you can read your Inbox, and send messages via their sending server, but you can only do this from the facebook webpage. They have chosen not to expose the servers that do this to regular email clients. So to use facebook's email service to read or send your facebook account messages, you have to be logged into facebook's website.